# Proof of a relation of Stickelberger element

Tags: summation, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I am reading the book *Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields by Lawrence C. Washington* and I am stuck in proving the relation  $\varepsilon_i \theta = \frac{1}{p} \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} a{\omega}^{-1}(a)\varepsilon_i$ (the last relation on the attached image). It is mentioned that we have to use the identity (d) $\varepsilon_\chi \sigma = \chi(\sigma)\varepsilon_\chi$ somehow.

My approach:

$\varepsilon_i \theta = \frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} a{\omega}^{i}(a) \sigma(a^{-1}) \cdot \frac{1}{p} \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} a{\sigma_a}^{-1}$ (From the definition of $\varepsilon_i$ and $\theta$)

$= \cdots$

$= \cdots$

$= \frac{1}{p} \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} a{\omega}^{-i}(a)\varepsilon_i $

$=B_{1,\omega^{-1}} \varepsilon_i $

How do I use (d) to fill the gaps in the proof? Please, help me.

[image]